# Disabling entire column in extjs 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a simple grid of multiple columns and each column editable fields. When I call `column.disable()` only the header of the column is getting disabled and the fields in the column are still editable. How can I disable all the fields in the column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in combination with the beforeedit event handler, you can use a renderer to alter the tdStyle of the cell to indicate it is disabled:

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
    var column = this.getHeaderContainer().getHeaderAtIndex(colIdx);
    if (column.disabled) {
        meta.tdStyle = "opacity: 0.4;";
    }

    return value;
}
```

tdCls is even better and allow more fine tuning of the appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `disable` method after render your [editor](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.RowEditor).
I use [beforeedit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-beforeedit) event for disable my fields
For example:

```
beforeedit: function (editor, context) {
    ...
    editor.editor.down('onetomanyeditor').disable()
    ...
},
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help. I can disable the editing of the fields but how do I bring the grey mask (to indicate they are uneditable) like I get in the header ?

Comment: The code that I wrote above should do this. You only have to indicate the path to your field

Comment: Show a more detailed example with your field and editor